# Using updatepanel initial working well but after some time not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am putting my linkbutton in the updatepanel and is working fine 
But if i put that page open for an hours together and then click that linkbutton, than the click event of that linkbutton is not called.
If i want to call that event i have to refresh that page and than it start working fine.

My .cs code(aspx.cs) for that link button is

```
protected void lnkcontact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("index.aspx?name=6");  
}
```

my design page code(aspx)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>                            
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="bottom-link" ID="lnkcontact" runat="server" OnClick="lnkcontact_Click">CONTACT</asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There was no need to write the code as all is working properly the only problem is that

**"if i put that page open continous without any work doing than why that linkbutton click event is not called after some time?"**

Comment: Might be a session/authentication timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to do 2 things to gather

1 > Follow the instruction as Ratna said.

for eg:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel10" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="180000">
  </asp:Timer>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

2 > Make asynchronous postback of the button you want to make click in updatepanel

for eg:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel15" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="" EventName="" />//this is asynchronouspostback
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So this to gather form code as

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel10" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="180000">
  </asp:Timer>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel15" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Upload File" OnClick="btn_upload_file_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />//this is asynchronouspostback
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the code but the way .net behave i.e you are using session and viewstate. and they both tends to get destroy after a amount of time. To circumvent either make your page not to use the two things or the easiest thing you can do is to place a timer which will just postback so that session and viewstate dosent get expired. Hope this is clear.

Comment: And this will result in a "psuedo-no-op" since it is inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: but here nor i m using viewstate nor use of session than how this problem occurs??

Comment: yes, you are using it,but you may not know, try disabling viewstate for every control and see if it helps. I will suggest to use timer instead. Also remove the update panel and then test itas you are doing now(after 1 hour), you will get an error, what the error is that? please give detail of that.

Comment: but sir i have read that viewstate value make store in page till the page get destroy or redirected to other page.

Comment: I have put timer inside update panel but it refreshes the whole page and also the code contain in pageload event

Comment: place your timer in its own updatepanel, also setcontidional update of updatepanels currently in use. Please see that I gave you the easiest and very quick solution but it seems your page too complex, try keeping your session alive by using a handler and jquery. If you need help just comment back i will help you to sort it out.

Comment: One more thing you are using link button just to redirect? why you dont use hyperlink instead? Any reason for this biasing?? Try to use html controls when ever possible it is lighter than server controls.

Comment: in its own update panel it means i have to take one more updatepanel for a timer..??

Comment: yes one more and dont forget to set condition update of other updatepanel otherwise they will refresh to their default value.

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="6000">
                            </asp:Timer>
                         
                         </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>....still whole server side page_load get refreshes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40295/discussion-between-mitesh-jain-and-ratna)

Comment: it is working some time but some time its not working